# CMD not recognised in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project which when i run it builds successfully but does not start the server instead it prints out the following "**'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**". 
i have actually tried re-installing netbeans but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What server you try to start?

Comment: glassfish server version 3.1.2

Comment: Do you try somthing like this tutorial http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-entapp.html ?

Comment: i finally figured out a way around it, when i tried accessing 'cmd' from the command prompt manually, it gave me same error, so i had to edit the environment variables path to point to 'c:\windows\system32' then i restarted netbeans and tadaaaaaaa, it works perfectly.

Comment: i didn't mention this variant before, because i never see the case where this variable is not defined) i think it's so obvious. But anyway it's so good that you solve this problem by yourself!.

Answer (score 7):

This not an issue with your IDE or in MAVEN.Check your "system32" is correctly defined in the `PATH` environment variable in windows.Before this verify your JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME paths are correct

```
Path = %SystemRoot%\system32;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add C:\Windows\System32 to your Path variable in environment variables and it should work.