# 'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, maven-3, netbeans-8

When I build my project in netbeans me it shows:

```
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.`
```

I'm using jdk 8 and maven 3.3. My path system variable is:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;D:\POS\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Would you explain a little bit  ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CMD not recognised in Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491928/cmd-not-recognised-in-maven)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file - Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723364/make-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So far I understand this is not your **IDE** issue.Check your "system32" is correctly defined in the PATH environment variable .

```
Path = %SystemRoot%\system32;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for suggestion but i have already this path in that path variable still i can' t run any command,So can you please help me ?

Comment: Did you restart you cmd after initializing it?

Comment: yes i restarted cmd and tried again but not working for me.

Comment: In that case, you issue a new question with screenshot. Anyway, one more question which path do you use?

Answer (score 4):

you can get it worked in anyone of below ways

1. Set path to system32 `c:\windows\system32` instead of `%SystemRoot%\system32`
2. Go to system32 folder then search and find `cmd.exe`
3. Use `command` instead of `cmd.exe`

Answer (score 2):

One variable named `Path` was already set but i created a new variable which is `PATH` so it replaced the `Path` variable so `Path = %SystemRoot%\system32;` got deleted.

SO the conclusion is you were trying to install java or maven and you replaced Path with PATH and its gone.

So set the SystemRoot path in environment variable something like below.

PATH = `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;`

Answer (score 1):

We can get cmd.exe with already setted System root path in very simple way

1. simply copy cmd.exe from Windows/System32 folder and paste it in directory where it is needed.

Comment: although this would work, it's a bad idea, to work around a misconfigured system instead of correcting the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

And easy workaround without using the environment variables path is to put the full path to the exe file as shown in the example below. First command doesn't work...Second works after putting the full location.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

to solve this problem add "system32" to your system environment variables (and user environment variables as well, add to both just in case)

for me this was the link

C:\Windows\system32

Comment: Your answer will be more complete if you add an example on how the `PATH` would look like. You can even further improve that if you add link(s) to where it is described where `cmd` resides and what it does.

Comment: The OP has already demonstrated that `%SystemRoot%\system32` is in their System 'Path'. In addition, there is already an existing answer which offers the same advice. As such I'm unsure why you've decided to submit this as an answer.