# why Netbeans Maven Project showing an Error: 'cmd' is not recognized

Tags: java, maven, jsp, netbeans

**Error Description:**
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I'have got the same issu, In my cas the GlashFish server was not started : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907346/maven-wont-open-browser-on-run-file-with-netbeans-8

Answer (score 1):

So far I understand this is not your IDE issue.Check your "system32" is correctly defined in the PATH environment variable .

```
Path = %SystemRoot%\system32;
```

as mentioned here: ['cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035577/)