# How can I use Windows cmd from within Julia?

Tags: cmd, julia

I’m trying to call cmd commands via Julia in Windows. According to multiple examples I've seen, including the [official documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/running-external-programs/), this should be as easy placing the command in backticks and then executing it using `run`.

For example:

```
mycommand = `dir`
run( mycommand )
```

But when I try this I get an error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: IOError: could not spawn `dir`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
```

To me the error indicates that Julia is looking for a file named dir and does not attempt to execute it as a command in cmd.

What am I doing wrong? How do I tell Julia that this is a command that is to be executed in the terminal and not a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
run(`cmd /c dir`)
```

as `cmd.exe` is the executable you need to run.

Comment: That produces a very similar error: ERROR: LoadError: IOError: could not spawn `cmd /c dir`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)

Comment: This is strange - it works for me. And what does happen if you write `cmd /c dir` after pressing `;` (switching to shell mode)? If it does not work then does running `cmd /c dir` work when you pass it as a command in the terminal?

Comment: In shell mode I get the same LoadError as written in my previous comment. In a regular Julia non-shell terminal it gives the error: “ERROR: syntax: extra token "dir" after end of expression”. In both cases I’m writing it without any backticks around the expression.

Comment: I am asking what happens if you write `cmd /c dir` in Windows prompt (not in Julia). Also what version of Windows are you on?

Comment: If I write “cmd /c dir” in the windows command prompt I get “'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command”. But I don’t understand why I would write that in the windows command prompt, normally I would just write “dir” and that does work. I’m using windows 64 bit windows 10.

Comment: I think that this question is a duplicate of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035577/cmd-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or  and this is a misconfiguration of Windows obviously not Julia related

Comment: Przemyslaw is right. I wanted you to test it in Windows prompt to check if `cmd` is in `PATH`. Apparently it is not (and it should be - as any other program you want to invoke without passing a full path to it).

Comment: BTW on my Win10 machine ``run(`dir`)`` just works without any special actions

Comment: It is probably that "bare" `dir` in your system redirects to `ls`. It works also for me because of this, but if Julia was started under `cmd` then bare `dir` outputs control sequences to the terminal while `cmd /c dir` does not.

Comment: I’ve added cmd.exe to my path and run(`cmd /c dir`) now works from Julia. But that is still not really what I wanted. I was looking for a way to call instruction from Julia in the same way a .bat script would run them. So if I write “D:” the terminal should change to the D drive, if I then write “cd D:\myFolder” it should change to that folder, if I then write “startMyProgram.exe” it should start a program. If I do this in a Julia terminal: “run(`cmd  D: cd D:\myFolder startMyProgram.exe´)” the Julia terminal changes to a windows cmd terminal and none of the other commands are executed.

Comment: This is not the way how `cmd.exe` in Windows was designed AFACIT. You should have a  better experience with interacting with shell under Linux.