# Anaconda Environment Activation

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, environment-variables

I recently downloaded Anaconda3 on Windows 7, and I am having trouble activating my environments.

```
C:\> activate py34
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried restarting and reinstalling to no avail. Could it be that the Anaconda installer did not add the software to my PATH environment variable?

Comment: Please always add error messages in code blocks not as images.

Comment: Ok, will do, thank you for bringing that to my attention. Can anyone help me with this error?

Comment: What is your Windows version? Did you modify your PATH environment variable? There should be system32 listed in your PATH: `Path = %SystemRoot%\system32;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you modify your PATH environment variable?

There should be system32 catalog listed in your `PATH`, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/32035723 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21672609:

```
Path = %SystemRoot%\system32;
```